# .htaccess - ignore rewrite rules for declared directories

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm working with a wordpress install that's in a subdirectory and uses the standard forwarding protocol as defined in the codex.

```
public_html/
  - index.php
  - .htaccess
  wp/
    - All Wordpress files
  passwordDir/
```

`passwordDir/` is a password protected directory.  With the default wordpress pretty-permalinks htaccess file, it gives a wordpress 404 error instead of prompting for a dom password.

We tried several solutions, but ultimately, [this](http://kb.siteground.com/how_to_exclude_a_folder_from_wordpress_permalinks/) one gave us the closest to what we wanted:

```
//  Add an addition '/' to the rewrite rule.

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . //index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

So instead of `RewriteRule ./index.php[L]`, it is  `RewriteRule .//index.php [L]`.

What we lost here is the wordpress 404 page.  If a user accesses a url that doesn't have a page-slug without a trailing slash, it shows the host-404 page instead of the WP-404 page.

Is there a way to retain the forward to the wp-404 AND get to the password protected directories?

Comment: 2 slashes before `index.php` in target URI is same as `/index.php` or just `index.php`. Is `passwordDir` a sub directory of `wp`?

Comment: No, passwordDir is an htaccess password protected dir in root public_html dir.  WP htaccess overrides the root directory, but only ones that are password protected.